# How to watch for $scope changes in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like this:

```
app.directive('selectedForm', function(MainService) {
    return {
        scope: {
            formName: '=currentForm'
        },
        restrict: 'E', 
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.$watch('formName', function(oldV, newV) {
                console.log(iElm);
                if (someCondition) {
                    MainService.getForm($scope.formName).then(function(re) {
                        iElm.html(re);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But, the problem is I cannot watch for changes. I have a `<select>` element in DOM that changes the value of `currentForm` usign `ngModel`. But, even though I select an option, the `watch` function is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same `$watch` in `angular directive` in the same way like you use in `angular controller`. Instead, change it to something like this:

change your `html` select element to something like this:

```
<select model="selectedElements">
    ...
    ...
</select>
```

and inside your directive, change your `$watch` to:

```
...
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.$watch('iAttrs.model', function(oldV, newV) {
...
```

*See also: [Is it ok watch the scope inside a custom directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800675/is-it-ok-watch-the-scope-inside-a-custom-directive)*

---

**EDIT:**

The code in your case to watch the value of `<select ng-model='currentForm'> ... </select>` would be:

```
...
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.$watch('iAttrs.currentForm', function(oldV, newV) {
...
```

---

**EDIT 2**

updates as per comments:

In your html

```
<selected-form ng-model="currentForm"></selectedForm>
```

and in your controller

```
...
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.$watch('iAttrs.ngModel', function(oldV, newV) {
...
```

---

**EDIT 3**

see this updated plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/v5EnmpQ9UtApnM5ErnYi?p=preview

Comment: So, I can't watch for changes in `$scope`...?

Comment: You can. All I'm saying is that you can't use `$watch` in the same way like you use in your controller.

Comment: I have seperate directives: `<select ng-model='currentForm> ... </select>` and `<selected-form></selected-form>`

Comment: I'm having a little trouble still. The watch function is not being executed on changes of `name` attribute `<selected-form name={{currentForm}}></selectedForm>`. I'm using this: `$scope.$watch(iAttrs.name,function(oV,nV){});` @rD

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed see **EDIT 2** of my answer

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/v5EnmpQ9UtApnM5ErnYi?p=preview